# Контент наезжает на футер при респонсив верстке

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Суть проблемы в следующем. Есть 2 колонки контента, в одной текст, который должен быть 1 размера и прокручиваться по скролу, если больше, а с другой слайдер. При увеличении масштаба браузера и слайдер и текст наезжают на футер и отрывают его от низа.

Подскажите, в каком месте я туплю, точнее я догадываюсь, что контент у меня обозначен жестко, в пикселях, но иначе как добиться скрола у контента? Скину сайт увидеть первому живому эксперту)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй для боди задать :

```
position:relative;
/*отступ величиной с высоту футера*/ padding-bottom:твое значение;
```

для футера :

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

вот пример:http://jsfiddle.net/6w4J2/1/

а вообще ссылку в студию=)